# What does "Myrna" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have a text, where author thanks

> Meg McKeen, for being the best Myrna a girl could ask for.

Alisson Hammer "You, Me and Us".

Who is Myrna? Google directs me to Myrna Loy, but I don't see any connection to somebody/something, what "a girl could ask for".

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: I see the book is a novel. If this is a dedication, it may be something personal to the author and her dedicatee.

Comment: I'd like to suggest it may be a reference to the character Myrna Minkoff from the novel *A Confederacy of Dunces.* In the novel, Myrna is an idealistic activist type person who is fascinated with the main character, Ignatius. She encourages him to take up many semi-foolhardy crusades to support progressive causes. Eventually she takes it upon herself to "save" Ignatius. Ultimately Ignatius and Myrna have a "love-hate" relationship. It could be that the author sees Meg McKeen as a Myrna-like figure in her life ...  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this sentence appears on the book's dedication page rather than in the main text. Such dedications sometimes contain "inside jokes" or references that only the author and the person mentioned in the dedication are meant to understand. So it could well be that only Alisson Hammer or Meg McKeen can answer this. Rest assured, it's nothing to do with the general English language.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase is "The best *X* a person could ask for" which means "the best possible example of an *X*." It means the person being thanked is the most perfect possible version that the author could hope to know or be friends with.

Usually this is something like "the best **editor** a person could ask for" or "the best **wife**" or "the best **mother**" or something like that. Here the author says Meg McKeen is the best possible **Myrna**. This is probably an inside joke or reference between the author and Meg, as others said.

And instead of referring to herself as just "a person" asking for something, Hammer refers to herself as "a girl." The writer referring to themselves as "a husband" or "an author" is also common.

Comment: Keen insight (pun intended). +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Some websites of the meanings of names state that Myrna means "beloved". *If* this is true (because other websites state different meanings), and *if*  Hammer and McKeen know about it ("only Alisson Hammer or Meg McKeen can answer this" - TypeIA), then it's possible that Hammer is making an inside joke of it. My real name also means "beloved" in another language, and I once made a joke about it with a friend who has the same name.